# Using Youtube API in android?

Tags: java, android, xml, youtube-api

```
public class MainActivity extends YouTubeBaseActivity {

Button b;
private YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView;
private YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener onInitializedListener;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    youTubePlayerView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.view4);
    onInitializedListener = new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
            youTubePlayer.loadVideo("KRavtGE-qsI");

        }

        @Override
        public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {

        }
    };

    b= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            youTubePlayerView.initialize("my key",onInitializedListener);
        }
    });

}
}
```

XML FILE

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="368dp"
    android:layout_height="495dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="173dp"
        android:text="Button" />

    <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
        id="@+id/view4"
        layout_above="@+id/button4"
        layout_marginBottom="109dp"
        layout_marginLeft="54dp"
        layout_marginStart="54dp"
        layout_toEndOf="@+id/button4"
        layout_toRightOf="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

When I click on the button of the app then It unfortunately stops. Can anyone please help me on this project? I build this project new version of android studio.I dint know why this happened.. cay any please help me in solve my problem..

Comment: please post crash logs

Comment: We need crash log to help you. Would you please add it to your question?

Answer (score 0):

Provide a valid key during the initialisation of youtube player.